# MSSQL - OLD to NEW table without duplicates

Tags: sql-server, unique

I have two old tables and wanna "synch" (or better setting new) two new tables... like that:

**tbl_old_event_categories (id, title)

tbl_old_events (id, title, cat_id)**

tbl_new_event_categories (id, category)
tbl_new_events (event_id, event, category_id)

The problem is that the new tables might already have values. So the IDs will changing (maybe). Because that I can't use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. :( I need to check it separate for each record. The tables are not unique (and I can't change that). :/

I created a JOIN to get:
**tbl_old_fullevents (event, category)** *//no IDs (integer) only the NAMEs (string)*

But how to create an INSERT INTO [tbl_new_events] with checking for existing [event]- and [category]-value? It's something like:

```
    IF(tbl_old_fullevents.event IS NOT IN(tbl_new_events.events)) {
     INSERT INTO new_events VALUE(
      NULL, //ID
      tbl_old_fullevents.event,
      IF(tbl_old_fullevents.category IN(new_event_categories.categories)) {
       new_event_categories.id //matched
      }
      ELSE {
       INSERT INTO new_event_categories VALUE (
        NULL, //ID
        old_fullevents.category
       );
       new_event_categories.id //last INSERT-ID
      }
     );
    }
```

Comment: The new Table is unique right? If not you are stuffed.

Comment: It's not clear from your explanation whether you have any value you can actually use to identify whether the record is the same (and should not be inserted). The pattern for what you want to do is trivial but if you don't have unique keys it's not much use

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MERGE` syntax. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx for examples.

You can't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because that's mysql.

Comment: [And some ideas on why you maybe shouldn't use `MERGE`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/can-i-optimize-this-merge-statement/44069#44069). :-)